# Defining Array in template.php Drupal

Tags: arrays, drupal, function

I have a drupal function that contains an array. I want to redefine one of the variables in that array. Do I just copy paste that entire function into template.php and change the variable to what I want it to be? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "a Drupal function"?  Your question doesn't have near enough info to make a reasonable answer.

Comment: Indeed. What function are you trying to tweak?